# Tengo un problema con pymongo en la función de autocontador

Tags: python, base-de-datos, discord.py, pymongo

Tengo un problema hace varios días: Tengo 3 colecciones/documentos en mi base de datos

**_id: user's discord id**

**Nombre: Nombre de discord**

**Pruebas: Numero de mensajes escritos**

Quiero que cada vez que escribas un mensaje se agregue +1 a tu contador de "pruebas", el problema es que siempre se queda en 1, no avanza... Llevo varios días buscando una solución. pero no puedo hacerlo y tampoco encuentro el motivo, se supone que se debería agregar +1 por cada mensaje que escribas

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    cluster = MongoClient("censored")
    db = cluster["Discord"]
    collection = db["Messages"]
    sid = message.author.id
    name = message.author.name
    collection.update_one({"_id": sid}, {"$set": {"Proofs": ++1}})
    await message.channel.send("A test was added to your count")
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estas usando el operador equivocado. El que tú necesitas el operador de incremento **$inc**

Cambia esta línea:

```py
collection.update_one({"_id": sid}, {"$set": {"Proofs": ++1}})
```

por esta:

```py
collection.update_one({"_id": sid}, {"$inc": {"Proofs": 1}})
```

y asegúrate que el campo Proofs sea un entero

Comment: Eso me sirvió, muchísimas gracias, tendría otra consulta; ¿Cómo puedo enviar los valores para que se vean de una manera mas "bonita"?

Ejemplo: Pruebas: 0

Comment: Eso es simple: formatea strings a tu gusto, como por ejemplo: `mi_string = f"Pruebas: {mi_variable}"`. Luego ponlas en donde necesites.